# Passport-azure-ad Nodejs access token validation error

Tags: node.js, passport.js, azure-ad-b2c, passport-azure-ad

I am using passport-azure-ad on my nodejs api project to authorize requests that are coming in with an access token,
I keep getting this error during the authorization process:

AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"","pid":20016,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: Error: unable to get local issuer certificate","time.

I dont know what could be causing this

Answer (score 0):

Here is the quick solution but it is not secure.

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

It is not secure because this above command fetchs the modules from the server even if the server is not have valid identity or not have valid certificate.

Here is the [secure way](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cafile). You can add any number of CA certificate that you required to identify servers. The certificate should be in `“Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)(PEM)”` format.

Read more [here](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value).